# Problem with SSL on tomcat with this code

Tags: java, servlets, ssl

i would like to know what this error means: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: **unable to find valid certification path to requested target null**

this error appers when i try to use this state:

```
private HttpState setcookies(String msg){
    HttpState state = new HttpState();
    String[] splited;
    String authToken=null;
    String tokenSecret=null;
    splited = msg.split(" ");
    authToken=splited[1];
    tokenSecret=splited[2];
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie cookie = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie("winter.servebeer.com", EXTCOOKIE+"accessToken", authToken);
    cookie.setPath("/OfeliaP");
    state.addCookie(cookie);
    cookie=new org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie("winter.servebeer.com", EXTCOOKIE+"tokenSecret", tokenSecret);
    cookie.setPath("/OfeliaP");
    state.addCookie(cookie);
    return state;
}
```

Comment: This is an SSL handshake failure.It was not possible to verify certificate.Does it fail in the client or server side?

Comment: client. Client is trying to make a post on server

Comment: What kind of certificate the server sends?Is it in your truststore?

Comment: ssl normal ones ? everything works if i access via web. what is odd in this error is target null

Comment: What do you mean via web?Plain HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Comment: Using https everything works well..

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this kind of thing.  I suspect that the problem is that you've configured the server to present the certificate chain in the wrong order.  Web browsers typically don't care, but the Java implementation of SSL / TLS requires the certificates in the chain to be in the right order.